# Created a Moodle website using google API account login working since last two years but now it stop working

Tags: php, web, google-api, moodle

I created a Moodle website two years ago and I am using google account login using google API and for the last two years it works fine but now every time I login using the same google account it wont work I can't login and access the website.

When I try to Login this will show

seed.jss.ph.education%2Fadmin%2Foauth2callback.php%3Fstate%3D%252Fauth%252Foauth2%252Flogin.php%253Fwantsurl%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fseed.jss.ph.education%25252F%2526sesskey%253DH7bvWEyZcB%2526id%253D1%26code%3D4%252F0AWtgzh7CPfju1hbYax4IhNvFSTqHDCFVNf6urRdM5pOoGz_yAGuVY9NkkyfZi7TD4fft3g%26scope%3Demail%2520profile%2520https%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fuserinfo.email%2520openid%2520https%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fuserinfo.profile%26authuser%3D4%26hd%3Djss.ph.education%26prompt%3Dnone&h=AT2rS1BBxsvT0ccCVA7Oi0EfkVJn-yDtaVhP12XHIQ5RW2D7dH0FziSU1lFjzJOxFtYWJ5P8nH5kjVIIZbLBZqZFM_I26XkdH86UeMnjKNYTF4eKdYuiO5fddGNm8u8cGETGPw

can someone help us please?

I already tried searching for answers with my problem, but I can't find it.  I already check the web servers the whole site is ok but when it comes to logging in using the google account it won't access the Moodle website.

Answer (score 0):

The callback url is working, its displaying a session time out error with the parameters above, which is correct

So I'm guessing this error is displayed on the Google website not the Moodle website?

Double check the Google settings are correct and enabled

There are some instructions here

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/OAuth_2_Google_service

Start by going to https://console.developers.google.com/

Then select your project > Credentials > OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

Check its enabled

The url should be https://seed.jss.ph.education/admin/oauth2callback.php

Note it should be https not http

If that looks okay, then maybe double check the client id and client secret are correct in Moodle

Site admin > Server > OAuth2 services > Google

The default for the service base url is https://accounts.google.com/